# How can I determine the likelihood that a visitor will visit again?

Tags: probability, predictive-models

### The Question

I am currently working on an analysis of my company's customers and their visiting patterns. In particular, one question that has come up is:

> Given that a visitor has visited `x` times, how likely is it that they will visit again at least once?

Intuitively, it seems to me that there is a meaningful relationship here. We have some customers who will visit once and then never again, while other customers are very committed to us and will come fairly regularly - I would think that the more often you have visited, the more likely you are to keep coming.

### My Work Thus Far

I tried to plot this relationship.

`y = [# of visitors with at least x+1 visits] / [# of visitors with at least x visits]`

[image: A scatterplot depicting number of visits along the x-axis and percentage of visitors returning for another visit along the y-axis. There is a trendline showing that the likelihood of a return visit starts at about 60%, arcs upwards close to 100%, and then eventually descends back toward 0%.]

And this results in a nice curve that seemingly supports my intuition. Only about 60% of our first-time visitors return for a 2nd visit. But 99% of our visitors with 150 visits return for a 151st visit - they really like us. From there, the curve drops, and eventually reaches 0% - the visitor who has seen us over 904 times. Maybe they will come for visit 905, but we just don't know yet. But eventually, even the dedicated visitors stop coming - such is life.

### The Problem

From here, I thought I could use this data to predict the likelihood of an individual returning based upon their previous number of visits. But as I think about it, it seems to make less sense that I had originally thought.

For instance, if I look at someone who visited once, 10 years ago, it seems to me there is a much smaller than 60% chance that they will suddenly return. And in fact, by definition, that visitor from 10 years ago is part of the 40% we measured.

Perhaps part of the issue, is that some of the customers included in my data have completed their lifespan with us (i.e. they will never return) and some are just beginning. Given the way I'm looking at the data right now, there is no differentiation between customers who only came once because they don't want to come again and customers who only came once because their first visit was yesterday and they haven't had time to come back yet.

**So how can I approach this problem? Where did my thinking break down?**

Comment: You could try evaluating if a customer's visits follow some parametric birth process. "birth" = "a visit occurs"; the likelihood of "a new visit occurs" depends both on the time passed since last birth, and the amount of births the customer has had.